NFC - android / iphone - Identifying Phone to PN532 NFC Reader
I'm working with an ESP32 and a PN532 NFC tag reader, and I've successfully used the code below to read NFC tags.
However, I’d like to identify a phone (Android/iPhone) by placing it near the PN532.
I want to build an iOS/Android app that sends a same NFC data each time, as currently, Android sends a different ID every time a phone is placed near the PN532.
Is there a way, or do you have any suggestions, on how I can use a phone to send an ID or some consistent data to the PN532 so I can identify that it's my phone and perform a specific task based on that?

I need something similar to what's shown in this video:
https://youtu.be/_kW7hPiGi2o?t=27 But I’m not sure how the phone sends
the same ID. My Android phone sends a different ID each time, and my
iPhone doesn't send anything.

#include <Wire.h>
#include <PN532_I2C.h>
#include <PN532.h>

PN532_I2C pn532i2c(Wire);
PN532 nfc(pn532i2c);

void setup() {
    nfc.begin();
    nfc.setPassiveActivationRetries(0x02);
    nfc.SAMConfig();
}

void loop() {
    uint8_t uid[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    uint8_t uidLength;
 
    if (nfc.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, &uid[0], &uidLength, 100)) {
        String hexString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < uidLength; i++) {
            hexString += String(uid[i] >> 4, HEX);
            hexString += String(uid[i] & 0x0F, HEX);
        }
        Serial.print(hexString);
    }
}


You will need to implement Host-card-emulation (HCE) on Android.  You can't do it on iOS without a specific entitlement from Apple and VAS support in your NFC reader.

It's a security feature that devices send a random ID, in NFC the ID never was designed to be unique it just needs to be different from any other Tag in it's limited range.
With Android you can implement an App with HCE and then send a consistent user data payload to identify a phone, the app https://github.com/underwindfall/NFCAndroid shows an example of Android HCE.
With iOS it's not really possible for a normal developer to do, Apple restrict this too much.
If you just want to send data then you could reverse the roles.
The PN532 allow you to emulate various NFC Tags, then you can write an App that writes your user data consistent payload to the emulated Tag. Both Android and iOS can write data to a Tag but might require the user start the app (Android and iOS normal apps can do things automatically when they see the right type of Tag, but each do this differently, so not sure you can create a emulated Tag and apps that works for both is unknown)

If you're willing to go lower level, and the PN532 allows you to send arbitrary APDUs, you can just issue VAS passes (with something like passninja.com) and then use this guide to figure out which APDUs to send to the reader: https://gist.github.com/gm3197/ad0959476346cef69b75ea0523214350
BTW if you don't know what APDUs are, you can read this: https://www.passninja.com/tutorials/nfc-protocols/what-are-apdus
